# How can I mimic legacy bank in my project?

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, query

I want to build a project where legacy bank interacts with blockchain networks (over CCIP). Please suggest me how can I mimic a legacy bank - as a separate project or any different idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad. A blockchain like Ethereum can provide some services, but a real bank does a lot more beyond holding funds.